# AWS MYSQL (mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002)) : cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I have a **t2.small** instance in **AWS** that has been running along for the better part of 10 months now without restarting the EC2 instance / the apache server / mysqld server and suddenly, as of a few minutes ago, it can't connect to the database.

I couldn't access any pages that connect to the database and attempting to login to phpmyadmin returns the error `mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory`

So while panicking, I did the following:

1. Attempted to restart the mysql server with `sudo service mysqld restart` but it just kept coming up with `STOPPED`
2. Restarted the EC2 instance
3. It lives (for now until it crashes again)

Since it has crashed, I'd like to know why it crashed and how to prevent it from crashing again.

I dug into the mysqld.log and found below info:

```
Version: '5.6.39'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2019-06-17 14:08:19 15623 [Warning] Buffered warning: Performance schema disabled (reason: init fa
iled).

2019-06-17 14:08:19 15623 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2019-06-17 14:08:19 15623 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2019-06-17 14:08:19 15623 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2019-06-17 14:08:19 15623 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-06-17 14:08:19 15623 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2019-06-17 14:08:19 15623 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8       
2019-06-17 14:08:19 15623 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO                 
2019-06-17 14:08:19 15623 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions           
2019-06-17 14:08:19 15623 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12                                  
2019-06-17 14:08:19 15623 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool           
2019-06-17 14:08:19 15623 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error. 
2019-06-17 14:08:19 15623 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.     
2019-06-17 14:08:19 15623 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB    
2019-06-17 14:08:19 15623 [ERROR] Aborting 
...
...(shutdown a bunch of plugins)
...
2019-06-17 14:08:19 15623 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql56/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

I searched around and found **Inconsistent InnoDB Buffer Pool Size** 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.KnownIssuesAndLimitations.html

Specifically, it details a solution to inconsistent buffer pool size by doing:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size = 536870912
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4
innodb_buffer_pool_size = (536870912 * 4) * 8 = 17179869184
```

**Questions:**

1. Have any of you encountered this? How did you go about solving it?
2. What's actually happening to the server? Am I actually really running out of memory for mysqld as the logs say **cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool**? (I always do `top` from time to time to check and there's always at least half of it free.)
3. Where did the above example from AWS get the number `536870912`? And where do I put the lines? (/etc/my.cnf)?

Thank you for reading and any comments or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1) I encoutered the same problem and got it solved by following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saQP9NjGQBI).

Comment: not sure if it's that one. I've never had to configure anything of the sort and a restart worked already. I need to know why it happened and how to prevent it from happening.

Comment: Maybe you need to increase the size of the innodb buffer pool size which is likely to keep the program stable..  Actually it might happen due to the installation of nginx or apache which take some process and memory which slows down the system. So increasing the size and restarting the mysql service solves it for you.